# What type of glass to use for shelves?

Tags: kitchens, shelving, glass

I have a cupboard that has glass items in it:

[image: Closed]
[image: Open]

I'm thinking it would be really cool if these were glass shelves.

Is there a special type of glass for this?  I'm thinking it's got to have some kind of rounded edge on it so nobody gets cut, but then is there some kind of glass that is less likely to get scratched as items are slid on & off the shelves?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of color choice, make sure you get tempered safety glass.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen 1/4 inch thick glass used in that sort of application.  A glass store can cut and edge it for you if you give them the measurements.  For extra coolness you could use colored glass.  While if you were doing this for commercial sale regs probably would require safety glass a DIYer can do whatever he wants for this.

It gives you a beautiful view of the dust on the shelves!

Comment: I hadn't thought about the dust!  That's a very good point.

Comment: That's why you want to use a darker glass like a deep red or blue or a brown.  As for scratching, anything with a hardness the same or greater can scratch something so glass on glass can scratch.  However you can easily drop down a thin layer of plastic on the glass - they sell plastic safety film specifically for this purpose it's designed so if the glass breaks the shards don't go everywhere.  You put it on the top so the stemware doesn't get scratched.  The film can get scratched but if it gets bad you just peel it off and replace it.

Comment: I finally got back to this project and have a quote from a local glass dealer.  They are offering tempered glass which seems fine, but don't know anything about a plastic film.  Will something like this do the trick? https://smile.amazon.com/HOHOFILM-Shatterproof-Adhesive-Protection-Security/dp/B07PDK2FH8/ref=sr_1_11?dchild=1&keywords=plastic+safety+film+for+glass&qid=1613679143&sr=8-11

Comment: regular glass on tempered glass is going to be the same as regular glass on regular glass.  It is certainly going to fret and scratch if you slide glass objects over the glass shelf.  Tempered glass is more expensive but if it is nicked in the slightest it can burst into glass gravel.  It's fine for windows but I cannot see the justification for using it here.  Just buy inexpensive 1/4 thick colored glass and put down a thin film of safety plastic on it and then not only will you not risk a scratch, if the shelf falls and cracks the shards won't go everywhere.